# Can't figure out why it isn't working. javascript calling data-key

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm working on a little project since I am a Javascript beginner. I have spent some hours on the same problem, and I just can't figure why it doesn't work. I would have rather find the problem myself, but I guess it is time to ask for help.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    const audio = document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
    console.log(audio);

    /* audio.currentTime = 0; 
    if(!audio) return;
    audio.play(); */
});
```

So I just can't figure out why I doesn't select the data key in my HTML, the console log say the audio is `null`.

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />

</head>
<body>


    <div id="main">
        <div data-key="68" class="key">
            <p>Press D for Dogs</p>
        </div>
        <div data-key="67" class="key">
            <p>Press C for Cats</p>
        </div>
        <div data-key="18" class="key">
            <p>Press P for Pigs</p>
        </div>
        <div data-key="70" class="key">
            <p>Press F for Frogs</p>
        </div>
        <div data-key="69" class="key">
            <p>Press E for Elephants</p>
        </div>
        <div data-key="71" class="key">
            <p>Press G for Goats</p>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/dog_x.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="67" src="sounds/cat_y.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="18" src="sounds/pig.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/frog.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="69" src="sounds/elephant.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/goat.wav"></audio>


    <script src="main.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your query needs editing:

```
document.querySelector('audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
```

There is no such thing as parameter expansion in strings enclosed in single quote marks (`''`).

Either concatenate the correct string like this

```
document.querySelector('audio[data-key="' + e.keyCode + '"]');
```

or use a template string ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

```
document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```